# Selecting only name of the month from a DateTime type

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am working on a small SQL Query which should return full name of the month instead of its number.
I was able to return number but not able to return its full name using `DATEPART` in `SQL Server` as follows

```
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, Delivery) AS Delivery FROM Deals
```

Above query returns 1 for January where a I wanted to return "January"

**Is there a better way I can solve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`DATENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms174395.aspx)** Function which Returns a **character string** that represents the **specified datepart** of the specified date

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, Delivery) AS Delivery FROM Deals
```

Or If you want `short month names or customized month names` and if you are using `SQL SERVER 2012+` use **[`Choose function`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213019.aspx)**

```
SELECT Choose(Datepart(MONTH, Delivery), 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'April', 'May', 
   'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec') AS Delivery
FROM   Deals
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Datename` like this.

`SELECT DATENAME(mm, Delivery) AS Delivery FROM Deals`.

It return a character string that represents the specified datepart of the specified date

MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms174395.aspx